# Subsets of a tuple with a fixed length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to have a function, `subset(("A","b","C","D"),3)`, which gives the following output:

```
("A","b","C")
("A","b","D")
("A","C","D")
("b","C","D")
```

How might I do this in python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `itertools.combinations` function was built explicitly for this purpose:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(("A","b","C","D"), 3))
[('A', 'b', 'C'), ('A', 'b', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('b', 'C', 'D')]
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`
>
> Return `r` length subsequences of elements from the input `iterable`.

Comment: technically `def subset(elements, size): return '\n'.join(list(itertools.combinations(elements, size)))` :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Probably intentional to be concise. This isn't about writing code on the behalf of other people, to be fair.

Comment: @AlexThornton I was honestly surprised no one asked him what his budget was before writing code for him :)

Comment: @AdamSmith - The important part here was showing the OP how to generate the combinations he wants.  After that, it would be trivial to put the code in a function `subset`.  Also, it is somewhat unclear what the output is supposed to be.  _Is_ it a string?  Or simply an example of the combinations he wants?  Because of the ambiguity, I decided to leave the definition of `subset` to the OP. :)